# How to set backgrounds for content-primary / secondary on jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, background

I have a simple jquery mobile page with a content-secondary and content-primary DIV. I want now, that content-primary uses the background of data-theme="a" and content-secondary the one of data-theme="b".

If i try it like this, it shows no background at all (only white color):

```
<div data-role="page" id="create-event" >

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed" >
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <div class="content-secondary" data-theme="a">

                <!-- content -->

            </div>

            <div class="content-primary" data-theme="b" >

                <!-- content -->

            </div>
        </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed" >  
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`data-theme` doesn't work with custom div's, it only works with div's with `data-role`. As such, you could resolve this by adding two `data-role=content` div's to the page with different `data-theme`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Rk2ac/)**

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
 <p>contents</p><br/>
 <p>contents</p>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
 <p>contents</p><br/>
 <p>contents</p>
</div>
```